# Bad Request with Azure Storage Simulator (v4.2) and Micorosft.WindowsAzure.Storage (v7.0.0) => Azure SDK 2.9

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

When trying to call CreateIfNotExistsAsync method of CloudBlobContainer (with "UseDevelopmentStorage=true" for connection string), I am getting following error:

*Exception: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException[T](HttpStatusCode expectedStatusCode, HttpStatusCode actualStatusCode, T retVal, StorageCommandBase`1 cmd, Exception ex) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\Shared\Proto
col\HttpResponseParsers.Common.cs:line 50
....*

At the end of exception stack trace, I see following information:

*Request Information
RequestID:6981043b-1ca2-4788-ba8e-bab39fb95956
RequestDate:Fri, 08 Apr 2016 19:18:21 GMT
StatusMessage:**The REST version of this request is not supported by this release
of the Storage Emulator**. Please upgrade the storage emulator to the latest versi
on. Refer to the following URL for more information: http://go.microsoft.com/fwl
ink/?LinkId=392237*

I am using the ***currently latest*** simulator (v4.2) as well as ***currently latest*** Micorosft.WindowsAzure.Storage library (v7.0.0). Should I be using anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 4.3 version of the emulator, which supports the 7.0.0 version of the .Net Client Library, will be released very soon. We are having some technical issues releasing it, but it's in the pipeline. For now you can use the older version of the client.

Sorry for the inconvenience!

**EDIT**: The 4.3 emulator is now up. Please respond if you have any issues.

Comment: I down graded the storage library to 6.2.0. It worked! Thanks for the update.

Comment: You should be able to get the newest emulator here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51657&Wt.mc_id=DX_MVP8656
Please respond if that doesn't work for you

Comment: t seems that 7.0.1-preview works with DNX core 5 but there is no emulator for that?.  I  succeeded with 6.2.2-preview. Thans Rudra.